# communication with two web services using came and spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

Hi I am new to camel and I want to communication with two web services  my requirement is :
array of object pass to one web service

> array[0] have school details so it will save in database using spring rest call("/register")
>
> array[1] have admin details so need to save in admin database using other spring rest service ("/register-admin") and generate username and password and return

I am trying to do that by using **("rest:post:register")** but camel and spring boot has started on different port so 404 getting

I used ("jetty:{uri}")  also but it is not working and if it will work then how we will pass object via request body

please help me to solve

thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try use the http4 component with bridgeEndpoint=true, like this.

.toD("http4//yourUrl?bridgeEndpoint=true");

I always do this way.